# Git completion: no bash file names completion anymore

Tags: bash, git, bash-completion, git-completion

I added to `~/.config/bashrc` this line:

```
. /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git
```

Bash completion works, but I lost Bash files completion, is it expected? Is it possible to have both?

Comment: Should be `. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`

Comment: @phd this path is empty on my Gentoo.

Comment: `/etc/bash_completion` ? `locate -b \\bash_completion` ?

Comment: @phd `/etc/bash_completion` does not exists on my machine, and I do not have `locale` app.

Comment: Hm, but now files completion works too..